# EventStore Bad Request (Invalid host) working in cluster

Tags: http, cluster, 400

I'm using EventStore with the following configuration :

```
---
RunProjections: All
ClusterSize: 2
Db: /opt/eventstore/db
DiscoverViaDns: false
GossipSeed: 10.0.100.11:1113
GossipOnExt: false
Log: /opt/eventstore/logs
Index: /opt/eventstore/indexes
IntIp: 10.0.100.10
IntTcpPort: 1112
IntHttpPort: 1113
ExtIp: 10.0.100.10
ExtTcpPort: 2112
ExtHttpPort: 2113
ExtIpAdvertiseAs: xx.xx.xx.xx (public ip)
AdminOnExt: true
```

My cluster works as expected but the UI is unavailable, displaying error

```
Bad Request (Invalid host)
```

If I change my configuration as a single node :

```
---
RunProjections: All
Db: /opt/eventstore/db
DiscoverViaDns: false
Log: /opt/eventstore/logs
Index: /opt/eventstore/indexes
IntIp: 10.0.100.10
IntTcpPort: 1112
IntHttpPort: 1113
ExtIp: 0.0.0.0
ExtTcpPort: 2112
ExtHttpPort: 2113
ExtIpAdvertiseAs: xx.xx.xx.xx (public ip)
AdminOnExt: true
```

the webui is available. So I tried to set  ExtIp to 0.0.0.0 for my cluster configuration as seen on many blogs post and forum discussions but then the cluster fails to start :

```
eventstored[22658]: [22658,13,10:02:10.495] ELECTIONS: (V=11) SHIFT TO LEADER ELECTION.
eventstored[22658]: [22658,13,10:02:10.495] ELECTIONS: (V=11) VIEWCHANGE FROM [10.0.100.10:1113, {a9c8292f-e342-4c53-b62c-fe82bac2d450}].
eventstored[22658]: [22658,07,10:02:11.407] Verifying hash for TFChunk '/opt/eventstore/db/chunk-000013.000000'...
eventstored[22658]: [22658,13,10:02:11.500] ELECTIONS: (V=11) TIMED OUT! (S=ElectingLeader, M=).
eventstored[22658]: [22658,13,10:02:11.500] ELECTIONS: (V=12) SHIFT TO LEADER ELECTION.
eventstored[22658]: [22658,13,10:02:11.500] ELECTIONS: (V=12) VIEWCHANGE FROM [10.0.100.10:1113, {a9c8292f-e342-4c53-b62c-fe82bac2d450}].
```

Any idea how to get the cluster AND the webUI working ?

Thank you.